# Positioning a div to the left with right-aligned div inside a container

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Desired Result]

With the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="floatingLeft">A right-aligned div</div>
    <div class="a">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="b">Ipsum Lorem</div>
    <div class="c">Other</div>
    <div class="d">Random</div>
    <div class="e">Tex</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this using pure css? Bonus points if the the right-aligned div can be vertically centered.

Thanks :)

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cob1wyz9/)**

Comment: Jsfiddle to serve as a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/cob1wyz9/

Comment: You can edit your original question in stead of posting a comment

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cob1wyz9/3/ ?

Comment: @GMolenaar , that's nearly perfect. Especially considering I'm doing this as an alternative to using html tables. Post it as an answer so I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in your comment ive added it as a answer.

Something like this? jsfiddle.net/cob1wyz9/3

```
.container {
   display: table;
}
.floatingLeft {
   text-align: right;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.container {width: 40%;}
.container > div {width: 50%; float: right; clear:right;}
.container > div.floatingLeft {float: left; text-align: right; padding-right: 3%}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="floatingLeft">A right-aligned div</div>
    <div class="a">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="b">Ipsum Lorem</div>
    <div class="c">Other</div>
    <div class="d">Random</div>
    <div class="e">Tex</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice but having a hard-coded width makes me feel like there has to be a better way.